# What does IsMRUEstablished mean?

Tags: windows-registry

For setting the default printers in the registry I can see three keys.

- Device  - This is the default printer for the user profile
- IsMRUEstablished
- LegacyDefaultPrinterMode  - This prevents windows updating the default printer

What does IsMRUEstablished do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, so this is an educated guess.

MRU stands for Most Recently Used. An MRU list is a list that contains devices or files of items that were accessed recently. For example, In old windows installations, you had a My Documents folder in the start menu that had an MRU List which listed documents that were opened recently.

Is MRU Established seems to be a similar thing. I would guess that this would indicate whether the printer has been used before as a validation method for managing default printers.